# In order queue: two kernels - one waiting for event and one not

Tags: opencl

Suppose I enqueue two kernels in an in-order queue.

The first kernel is set to only run when it receives a completion event,
while the second kernel is not waiting for an event.

Will the runtime execute the second kernel first in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An in-order queue will execute the items in the order you queue them, essentially giving each operation its predecessor as a wait event. Your second kernel should not be executed until after the first one in your example.

Out of order queues require you to manage the wait lists yourself, but have the advantage that tasks can be executed as soon as their prerequisites have been met. Just make sure your platform supports out-of-order queues before you end up troubleshooting a dead-end. See answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821293/opencl-command-queue-cl-queue-out-of-order-exec-mode-enable-not-working-macos).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, it looks like there aren't any out of order queue implementations out there, at least for discrete GPUs.

Comment: I think most AMD/ATI cards since 6xxx series should support out-of-order queues. But you're right, this is not yet a feature to rely on when distributing an application across vendors.

Comment: OoO queues are good feature, but not really a must. Thats why some vendors don't implement them, since it makes the life easier for the driver. And a good algorithm should not rely on out of order, should work as good with in order queues (or multiple queues).